# Apache, Python e mod_wsgi

Tags: php, python, apache

Senhores,
utilizo aplicações web simples, rodando em Apache2 e com PHP no servidor, para automatizar tarefas triviais na minha equipe de trabalho. Utilizo o PHP apenas para requisições LDAP e em BD, utilizando jQuery, lodash e JS puro para tudo o mais. Estou migrando muitas bases para CouchDB, o que facilita bastante no front-end.

Costumo enviar as requisições para o servidor com `$.ajax`, `$.post` e `$.get`. Por exemplo:

```
$.post({
  url: 'server/teste.php',
  success: res => {
   console.log(res);
  }
});
```

No servidor, tenho arquivos do tipo:

```
 <?php

$conn = ldap_connect("localhost", 10389) or die("Sem conexão\n");

if ($conn)
{
  ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
  ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
  $bind = ldap_bind($conn, 'uid=admin,ou=system', 'secret') or die ("Bind recusado\n");

  if ($bind)
  {
    $dn = 'ou=usuarios,o=bb,c=br';
    $filter = '(uid=*)';
    $attr = ['cn', 'sn', 'departmentNumber', 'ou', 'title', 'uid'];

    $pesq = ldap_search($conn, $dn, $filter, $attr) or die ("Pesquisa não realizada\n");

    if ($pesq)
    {
      $res = ldap_get_entries($conn, $pesq);
    }
  }
  ldap_close($conn);
}

print_r($res);
```

Isso é só um exemplo do código. Normalmente o retorno é em JSON.

Estou aprendendo Python e embora eu adore o PHP, scripts como esse são bem mais simples de escrever em Python, o que me fez buscar uma forma de portar minhas requisições.

Não quero utilizar frameworks, como Django, já que meu objetivo não é servir aplicações 100% Python. Eu só preciso enviar uma requisição ajax, deixar o Python coletar as informações que eu pedi e devolver para o JS um JSON para que o navegador faça o resto.

Já tentei cgi, tô apanhando muito do wsgi, mas não consigo fazer isso.

Alguém teria alguma luz sobre como usar o Python dessa forma? Quero continuar servindo as páginas em html e utilizar ajax para os scripts do lado do servidor. É possível?

Desde já, obrigado.

Comment: Servidor Linux?

Comment: Na verdade, em uma estação de desenvolvimento. Mac em casa e Windows no trabalho. O deploy será em um servidor Windows com Windows Server 2008.